# wget command fulfill http method HEAD

Tags: http, wget

I know that wget command can fulfill the post and get request, but how do I fulfill the HEAD method when I only want to the head part of the document using wget command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget -S --spider http://www.example.com
```

or you can use curl:

```
curl -I http://www.example.com
```