# wget solution to avoid downloading files already present in the mirror when Last-modified header is not provided

Tags: linux, unix, timestamp, wget

I want to refresh the mirror of a website which server is not set to deliver Last-Modified response headers.

`Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off. Remote file exists and could contain links to other resources -- retrieving.`

I do not have admin rights to that server.

I'd be happy to set wget to ignore files for which the file size is identical, but I have not found a way to accomplish that.

I want to minimize bandwidth and avoid downloading files again, even if they were different but with the same size.

How would I implement such filtering from the CLI?

Comment: Download the file to a temporary file, compare it with what you have in the mirror. If it's different, replace the mirrored file.

Comment: Perhaps should I qualify "minimize bandwidth".

I intend not to download the file again when sizes match as I am willing to skip the odd same size file with content changed.

Comment: I don't think HTTP provides a way to get the size of a file without downloading it.

Comment: @Barmar curl does:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/how-to-retrieve-downloadable-file-size-with-curl-command

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431676/wget-command-fulfill-http-method-head for how to do a `HEAD` request with `wget`.

Comment: @Barmar updated OP. The question is about filtering wget or another utility rather than pulling Last-Modified response HTTP header which the server does not support.

Comment: I thought the question was about how to avoid downloading a file if the size hasn't changed. Using `HEAD` will allow you to get the Content-Length, which you can compare with the file's length, then skip the download.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is what I want to do. How would you implement the size compare and download skip?

Comment: Something like `remote_length=$(wget -S --spider "$url" 2>&1 | awk '/Content-Length:/ {print $2}')`

Comment: `local_length=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")`

Comment: Loop over all the files, comparing those and downloading the file when they're different.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the pointers, I can do some testing over the next few days and see if I can write a command to implement the filtering.